# Chart JS V3 Tooltip styling location changed?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using Chart JS v.3.4 and I'm trying to style my charts tooltip with no luck so far. I added the options to `options.tooltips` but for some reason, they have no effect.
[image]

My full code is below. Is there maybe a configuration that blocks my options from working? Or did it changed at some point where the options go?

```
async function init_line_chart()
{

  var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext("2d");

  var data = [100, 140, 150, 130, 160, 120, 130];
  var suggestedMin = Math.max.apply(Math,data);
  var suggestedMax = Math.min.apply(Math,data);

  var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(500, 0, 100, 0);
  gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, '#4e62ff');
  gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, '#4e62ff');

  var gradientFill = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 200);
  gradientFill.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(78, 98,255, 0.25)');
  gradientFill.addColorStop(0.2, 'rgba(78, 98, 255, 0.12)');
  gradientFill.addColorStop(0.8, 'rgba(78, 98, 255, 0)');
  gradientFill.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(78, 98, 255, 0)');

  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [ 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
        datasets: [{
            label: "",
            borderColor: gradientStroke,
            pointBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',

            pointBorderWidth: 5,
            pointRadius: 5,
            fill: true,
            backgroundColor: gradientFill,
            borderWidth: 4,
            lineTension: 0.3,
            pointHitRadius: 1000,
            data: data
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        animation: {
            easing: "easeInOutQuint"
        },
        tooltips: {
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            bodyFontColor: '#d4d4d4',
            bodyFontSize: 14,

        },
        scales: {
            x: {
                grid:{
                    display:false,
                    drawBorder: false,
                },
                ticks: {
                    font: {
                        family: 'Comfortaa', // Your font family
                        size: 13.6,
                    },
                    color: "#d4d4d4"
                },
            },
            y: {
                grid:{
                    display:false,
                    drawBorder: false,
                },
                ticks: {
                    display: false, //this will remove only the label
                },
            }
       },
       plugins: {
          legend: {
              display: false
         },
       }

    }
  });

}
```

Is there maybe a configuration that blocks my options from working? Or did it changed at some point where the options go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [Migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html) the namespace has been changed to `options.plugins.tooltip`.

If you want to know where to put options for configuration of specific things you can go to that part of the docs and look for the `namespace` part, that will tell you where to put the options

Comment: Ok for some reason I missed that. But it works now.